# PHP $_POST not getting values

Tags: php, forms, post

So, I have this form: *(dead link)*

And this in the PHP:

```
$nume = $_POST['Nume'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];   
$telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];   
$judet = $_POST['Judet'];   
$persoana = $_POST['Persoana']; 
$mesaj = $_POST['Mesaj'];
echo "Valori memorate:"; 
echo $nume,$email,$telefon,$judet,$persoana,$mesaj;
echo "<br>";
```

But it shows up nothing... Any ideas?

I know the source code looks awful, but this is a page I've made 2 years ago when I was still learning the basics of HTML.

Comment: First port of call: Basic debugging. What does a `print_r($_POST);` result in?

Comment: Why the `enctype="text"` in the form?

Comment: You can view the soruce code to see the form. The print_r shows: Array ( ) ... I don't know , I've made that 2 years ago, can't remember, maybe that's unneccessary

Comment: Try `text/plain` as your enctype rather than `text`, or remove it altogether.

Comment: Removed enctype="text", still no results in print_r($_POST) ...

Comment: I just submitted the form, and I saw the values I typed in the print_r output

Comment: I just tried your form and it shows me a `print_r($_POST)` result that seems to have the values I entered. You probably got it working.

Comment: As far as I can see, now it works

Comment: Thanks guy, that type="style6" kept me swearing for about 45mins...

Comment: Hahaha. Lesson: Always [validate](http://validator.w3.org)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was something stupid:
I wrote:

```
<input name="Nume" class="form" type="style6" id="Nume" size="30" />
```

So the type was "style6" instead of "text" ... Damn, 45mins, 45MINS, for that type="style6", :|

Answer (score 4):

It may be the `enctype="text"` attribute in your form (which should auto-translate to `enctype="text/plain"`, I don't know). IIRC, that enctype is valid for GET requests only.